# SoapUI XML file getting error when i integrate soapui with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, soapui

Error Message:
    /root/.jenkins/workspace/soapui-project/build.xml:2: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.

This error message is shown when i have build on Jenkins of this code.this is a small part of my XML soapUI file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <con:soapui-project xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config"
    id="1c7cb62d-1a4f-4ac0-bf3b-8ffd21730d51"
    activeEnvironment="Default"
    name="build"
    resourceRoot=""
    soapui-version="5.4.0"
    abortOnError="false"
    runType="SEQUENTIAL"
    updated="2.2.0 2017-11-28T12:17:25Z">
       <con:settings>
          <con:setting id="com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.tools.soapui.TestRunnerAction@values-local">
    <![CDATA[<xml-fragment xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
      <con:entry key="Environment" value="Default"/>
      <con:entry key="Global Properties" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="TestSuite" value="getAttackCounts"/>
      <con:entry key="Password" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="TestRunner Path" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Tool Args" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Ignore Errors" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Host:Port" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="user-settings.xml Password" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="WSS Password Type" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Save Project" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Enable UI" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="System Properties" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Domain" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Coverage Report" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Export JUnit Results" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Export JUnit Results with test properties" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Open Report" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Project Properties" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Export All" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Project Password" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Report Format(s)" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="TestCase" value="getCounts"/>
      <con:entry key="Print Report" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Username" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Root Folder" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Select Report Type" value=""/>
      <con:entry key="Save After" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Add Settings" value="false"/>
      <con:entry key="Endpoint" value="http://172.20.16.98"/>
    </xml-fragment>]]></con:setting>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am getting that error message "The markup in the document preceding the root  element must be well formed",when i have integrate SoapUI XML file with jenkins.